# Парсинг страницы с авторизацией через Steam

Tags: python, requests

Мне нужно спарсить страницу https://skins-table.xyz/table_rust/ чтобы она отображалась так, будто перед этим я залогинился через свой аккаунт Steam. Для этого я написал следующий код (мои реальные данные заменены на строки по типу `my_session_id`):

```
import requests

session = requests.Session()

cookies = {
    "sessionid": "my_session_id",
    "steamCountry": "my_steam_country",
    "steamLoginSecure": "my_Steam_login_secure",
    "Steam_Language": "english",
    "sessionidSecureOpenIDNonce": "my_session_id_secure_open_id"
}

session.cookies.update(cookies)

response = session.get('https://skins-table.xyz/table_rust/')

print(response.content)
```

Не возникает никаких ошибок, однако в ответе сервера страница отображается так же, как у неавторизованного пользователя. Как сделать, чтобы она отображалась так, будто перед этим я залогинился через свой аккаунт Steam? Авторизация через steam происходит через сторонний сервис (в другой вкладке). Перекопал весь интернет, только на одном сайте нашел похожий вопрос, но ответ с того сайта мне не подошел. Буду благодарен за любую помощь.

Comment: Знаете, самое первое, что я пробую, когда сайт не хочет играть по-хорошему - копирую User-agent из своего хрома в заголовки.  Может, получится?

Comment: Уже пробовал, к сожалению не сработало.

Answer (score 0):

В словаре cookies:

```
cookies = {
"sessionid": "my_session_id",
"steamCountry": "my_steam_country",
"steamLoginSecure": "my_Steam_login_secure",
"Steam_Language": "english",
"sessionidSecureOpenIDNonce": "my_session_id_secure_open_id"
}
```

У вас указаны значения по всем ключам в кавычках. Таким образом, в сессию вы передаёте словарь со строками вместо своих данных. Вам необходимо спарсить свои данные, сохранить их в переменные и уже эти переменные передать в качестве значений ключей этого словаря.

Comment: Вместо строк в моем коде я передаю строки данных, которые я получил через панель разработчика, здесь же я заменил их на тексты по типу my_session_id, чтобы не указывать собственные данные в вопросе